# onclick not working with firebase query to read data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got an async function to read/print data from a Firebase collection. It works when I call it in the script as a function. However, as soon as I set it to a button with a click listener, it doesn't work.

I've tried changing it from async to a normal function however it won't work either as it says `querySnapshot.forEach((snap)` is not a function. I've also tried using the arrow notation, didn't work either, instead of an error it just wouldn't print anything on the console.

I give it a `crValue` and I want it to return all the documents in the collection  where the field `cr` is equals to `crValue`:

```js
const crValue = document.getElementById('crValue').value;

searchCrBtn.onclick = async () => {

    const patientQuery = query(collection(db, path), where('cr', '==', `${crValue}`));

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(patientQuery);
    querySnapshot.forEach((snap) => {
       console.log(`Document ${snap.id} contains ${JSON.stringify(snap.data())}`)
    });
```

I'm assuming the error is in:

```
querySnapshot.forEach((snap) => {
  console.log(`Document ${snap.id} contains ${JSON.stringify(snap.data())}`)
});
```

Because if I add `console.log(patientQuery)` and `console.log(querySnapshot)` before the piece of code above, the both work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is really hard to help with. What is the exact problem, and on which line does it occur? Is there an error message? Or otherwise, is there some log output that highlights what is wrong/unexpected?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry, the error message is "firebase.js:111 Uncaught TypeError: querySnapshot.forEach is not a function
    at searchCrBtn.onclick (firebase.js:111:27)" which is this line: querySnapshot.forEach((snap) {

Comment: In the code you shared in the first snippet in your question, that error should not occurs on the line you indicate as far as I can tell. Are you sure that is the exact code (and line) where you get the error?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, 100% sure...

Comment: OK, thanks for double checking. I just don't see how that error could happen here, so hope that somebody else spots it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No problem! Thanks for helping. I just posted a solution that seems to be working, kind of odd though... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Moving CrValue inside the onclick listener seems to have solved the issue. I'm assuming it was a scoping problem.

```js
        searchCrBtn.onclick = () => {
            // cr number given in the box
            const crValue = document.getElementById('crValue').value;
            // defining function
            async function getPatientInfo() {
                // listing all the documents in a given path where the cr number is equals to cr_value
                const q = query(collection(db, path), where("cr", "==", crValue));
                // getting the documents specified in q.
                const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
                //console.logging every document.
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                });
            }
            //caling the function.
            getPatientInfo()
        }
```

Also tried to define the function inside the listener and call it after.

Comment: Can you clarify what changed between the code in your question and the code in this answer?